How Can I Get the Value of a Route Parameter?
I'm working in Angular 18.
In my app.routes.ts file, I have the below:
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ShowComponent } from './components/show/show.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'setlist/:showdate', component: ShowComponent }
];

Then in my show.component.ts, I have:
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class ShowComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {

  const showdate = String(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('showdate'));
  console.log(showdate);
}}

Then, let's say I visit /setlist/123
showdate is null
What am I missing here?
Thanks!

There is an alternative method (v16+) for obtaining route parameters using withComponentInputBinding that avoids subscribing to activatedRoute.
In the simplified example below we use an input signal (v17+) of type string and then react to any changes using an effect
// app.config.ts

 provideRouter(APP_ROUTES, withComponentInputBinding()),

//  app.routes.ts

 { path: 'setlist/:showId', component: ShowComponent }

// show-component.ts

showId = input<string>(); // this is the bound parameter

 constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      const currentShowId = this.showId();
      if(currentShowId){
        this.loadShowDetails(currentShowId);
      }
    });
  }

  private loadShowDetails(id: string) {
    // Load show API call    
  }




The value you get from the paramMap, must match the value you set in the routing using :id ( { path: 'setlist/:id', component: ShowComponent } ), so it should be fetched as id.
When you navigate from setlist/1 to setlist/2, the same component is shown, hence there is no reload that happens on the component, to handle this, we have to trigger the initialization of the component again on route change.
To trigger when the route changes, we use the observable paramMap of ActivatedRoute which fires whenever the paramMap changes.
The route params are received as strings, so there is no need to convert it. In JS you can try converting it to .toString() instead of String
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
...

...
export class ShowComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.route.snapshot.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
        const showDate = paramMap.get('id');
        console.log(showdate);
        // reinitialize your component here!
      })
    );
}}


You're right, I had a mismatch of id & showdate in the code I provided, but they were matched correctly in my actual application.
I still can't get anything than a 'null' value. Is there anything I should be importing that I'm not?
